# Will Question on Work and Travel in Montréal be reopened after requested edits have been made?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, vote-to-close

I have posted a [question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/56996/how-to-find-jobs-on-a-working-holiday-in-qu%C3%A9bec-montr%C3%A9al-with-mediocre-french) about job-opportunities in Québec in general and Montréal in particular that are open to people who travel with an open work permit ("working holiday"). The question was closed for being off-topic and I was asked to narrow down the question, so that it might become on-topic. Now that I have edited the question accordingly, is there a chance that it will be reopened?

The question IMO now matches the on-topic requirements listed in the help center:

> working while on the go (WWOOFing, volunteer travel etc) - not
>   immigration or work visas

For what it's worth, I would also like to contribute an answer at a later date.

Comment: I voted to reopen after your edit. There are only two such votes as of now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it was reopened `Oct 18 '15 at 22:40` and remains Open at present.

At present it has one answer (+7) ... but no Acceptance.